# PReact useEffect doesn't trigger on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, preact

I want to do a recursive function which basically runs each time a folder has a subfolder under it, so I can take all the content from all the subfolders available.

Not sure what I am missing here, but the state change of subFolders does not trigger the useEffect which have it as dependency:

```
    const [imageList, setImageList] = useState([]) as any;
    const [subFolders, setSubFolders] = useState([]) as any;

    const getFilesFromFolder = (fileId: string) => {
        let noToken = false;
        
        const requestFunction = ((pageToken?: string) => {
            gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                q: `'${fileId}' in parents`,
                pageToken
            }).execute((res: any) => {    
                const token = res.nextPageToken && res.nextPageToken || null;

                const images = res.files.filter((file: any ) => 
                file.mimeType === 'image/jpeg' ||
                file.mimeType === 'image/png' ||
                file.mimeType === 'image/jpg'
                );
                
                setSubFolders([...subFolders, ...res.files.filter((file: any ) => file.mimeType === 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')]);
                setImageList([...imageList, ...images])

                if (token) {    
                    requestFunction(token);
                } else {
                    noToken = true;
                }
            }).catch((err: any) => {
                console.log('err', err)
            })
        });

        if (!noToken) {            
            requestFunction();
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (subFolders && subFolders.length > 0) {
            subFolders.forEach((subFolder: any) => {
                getFilesFromFolder(subFolder.id);
            });
        }
    }, [subFolders])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are basically looping over file structure and enqueueing state updates I'm going to just assume any issues you have are because you are using normal state updates. When these are enqueued in loops or multiple times within a render cycle they overwrite the previous enqueued update.

To resolve you should really use functional state updates. This is so each update correctly updates from the previous state, ***and not*** the state from the previous render cycle. It's a subtle but important difference and oft overlooked issue.

[Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
setSubFolders(subFolders => [
  ...subFolders,
  ...res.files.filter((file: any ) =>
    file.mimeType === 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
  ),
]);
setImageList(imageList => [...imageList, ...images]);
```

Comment: Nevermind, I did try it and still the useEffect doesn't get triggered, the weird thing is that the imageList state now updates correctly, but the subFolders don't

Comment: @SergiuTonț I see. Think you could create a running codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live? Sometimes when distilling your code down to a minimal, reproducible example you'll find the issue.

Comment: I actually changed it a little, I'm going to run the forEach directly in the request call for subfolders, so I don't have to update state anymore, it was kind of an extra step when I thnik about it.
Thanks a lot for the help tho